# Travelling to a conference in Frankfurt and unvaccinated

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, frankfurt

I am planning to visit Frankfurt from within the EU for a conference by plane. I am not vaccinated at all against COVID-19. Can I still travel to the conference?

Edit:
EU citizen living in Ireland, will be travelling from Ireland and will not have been outside Ireland before the flight.

Answer (score 2):

From the Irish [DFA](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-countries/germany/)

> Travel to Germany

> There are no COVID-19 restrictions in place for travel to Germany from Ireland. There is no requirement to present certificates of vaccination/testing for COVID-19, or to complete a Passenger Locator Form.

And for the return back from the [Irish Gov](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/77952-government-advice-on-international-travel/) :

> From Sunday 6 March 2022, travellers to Ireland are not required to show proof of vaccination, proof of recovery or a negative PCR test result upon arrival.

> There are no post-arrival testing or quarantine requirements for travellers to Ireland.

Yes, you will be able to attend

Comment: Note that a medical or FFP2 (N95 and KN95 are accepted as well) facemask fully covering your mouth and nose is to be worn at all times on public transport. That includes, but is not limited to, buses, trams, metros, subways, trains while they are on German territory, as well as airline flights which are either taking off from or landing in Germany during the whole flight. The only exceptions are while you are actively eating or drinking, and of course if you have a medical exception (for which you need to provide documentation). Also, different States have different rules about whether or not

Comment: … this only applies inside the vehicle or also in the station / airport. I generally am too lazy to research all the different laws and regulations and just wear a mask all the time inside train stations and airports.